# Hibernate dose not get default value of a FK key from sequence

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, sequence, default

In my Spring Boot (v2.5.3) project, Hibernate doesn't honor default value of a FK key (comes from a sequence) in parent entity and does not get a child entity instance.

Parent entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_entity")
public class ParentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

...

    @Column
    private String str1;

    @Column
    private String str2;

...

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    private ChildEntity childEntity;
}
```

relevant `schema.sql` snippets:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE child_entity_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 5 START WITH 1 CYCLE NOCACHE;

CREATE TABLE parent_entity (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    child_entity_id INTEGER DEFAULT child_entity_id_seq.nextval,

...

    CONSTRAINT pk__parent_entity__id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk__child_entity_id__child_id FOREIGN KEY (child_entity_id) REFERENCES child_entity(id),

...
);
```

relevant `data.sql` snippets:

```
INSERT INTO parent_entity(code, name)
VALUES ('sample string 1.1', 'sample string 1.2');

INSERT INTO parent_entity(code, name)
VALUES ('sample string 2.1', 'sample string 2.2');

...
```

I do get nicely initialized DB, with 2 instances of ParentEntity, business fields (str1, str2) filled in, their IDs generated and both non-null references to ChildEntity, according to the sequence.

But if I execute:

```
class ParentEntityTest {

    @Autowired
    ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Test
    void insert() {
        ParentEntity parentEntity1 = parentRepository.saveAndFlush(new ParentEntity().setStr1("sample1"));
        ParentEntity parentEntity2 = parentRepository.saveAndFlush(new ParentEntity().setStr1("sample2"));

        assertTrue(dte1.getId() < dte2.getId());
        assertNotNull(dte1.getChildEntity());
```

...the second assert fails - reference to ChildEntity is `null`
When I use H2 console to check the DB content, even there the values are empty, despite the inserts in `data.sql` previosuly filled foreign keys without issues.

Hibernate generates insert with `null`s and the DB honores it, instead of using default sequence.next, hence the newly inserted instances also bear nulls instead of instantiated ChildEntity.

`@GeneratedValue` on the `private ChildEntity childEntity;` field does not work.

How can I solve it?

Comment: You don't set the childEntity so it's null in the database. That's normal.

Comment: @grigouille "child_entity_id INTEGER DEFAULT child_entity_id_seq.nextval" gets ignored, thats the issue

Comment: try adding NOT NULL to child_entity_id

Comment: @grigouille it throws null not allowed for given field exception. Seems like the only option left is just setting the reference to child entity programmatically, as the default sequence.nextval is being ignored.